# SQL - Delete selected row/s from database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite new to SQL and I'm having issues with deleting a selected row/s from a table.

I've written a query that selects the desired rows from the table, but when I try to execute `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE EXISTS` it deletes all the rows in the database.

Here is my complete query:

```
DELETE FROM USR_PREF WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
    FROM USR_PREF
    WHERE USR_PREF.USR_ID = 1
      AND ((USR_PREF.SRV NOT IN (SELECT SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW.ENTITYT_ID
          FROM SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW
          WHERE SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW.USR_ID = 1
            AND SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW.ENTITYTYP_CODE = 2
            AND USR_PREF.DEVICE IS NULL)

      OR (USR_PREF.DEVICE NOT IN (SELECT SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW.ENTITYT_ID
          FROM SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW
          WHERE SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW.USR_ID = 1
            AND SEC_ENTITY_FOR_USR_ACTION_VIEW.ENTITYTYP_CODE = 3)))))
```

The select query returns the desired rows, but the DELETE command just deletes that entire table.

Please assist.

Comment: Your filter on the delete says "Delete if any record matches the following" You want to say "Delete where the record matches the following". You can remove `WHERE EXISTS (   SELECT * FROM USR_PREF` and it should behave as expected.

Comment: Interesting that you say it deletes the entire table.  As I read the query, it should get an error on `USR_PREF_T.USR_ID` because `USR_PREF_T` is not defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
That was just a syntax mistake. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause `WHERE EXISTS (SOME QUERY)` is the problem here. You are basically saying "Delete everything if this subquery returns even one result".

You need to be more explicit. Perhaps something like:

```
DELETE FROM USR_PREF
WHERE USR_FIELD IN (
    SELECT USR_FIELD
    FROM USR_PREF
    WHERE USR_PREF_T.USER_ID=1
        AND ((USR_PREF.SRV NOT IN ...
```

and so on... With this, only records that match records returned in your subquery will be deleted.